# Draw on bing maps?

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone, bing-maps

How can I draw on bing maps? Or actually I'd like to add a marker. I have detected coordinates and now I want to display this place on a map with a marker...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To draw lines on a map you use the `MapPolyline` element as a child of the `Map` control. To add a marker to the `Map` control, you add a `Pushpin` element as a child of the `Map` control. To add multiple items (lines or pushpins) you add a `MapItemsControl` as a child of the `Map` control and specify the `ItemsSource` and `ItemTemplate`.

The following code example shows a `PushPin` to display the current location, and a `MapItemsControl` to show waypoints on a route:

```
<maps:Map x:Name="_map"
            CopyrightVisibility="Collapsed"
            CredentialsProvider="Your API Key Here"
            LogoVisibility="Collapsed">
    <maps:MapItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding WayPoints}">
        <maps:MapItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <maps:Pushpin Background="{Binding BackgroundBrush}" Location="{Binding Location}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </maps:MapItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </maps:MapItemsControl>
    <maps:Pushpin x:Name="_current" Background="Blue" Location="{Binding CurrentLocation}"/>
</maps:Map>
```

This [blog post](http://babaandthepigman.wordpress.com/2010/10/06/databinding-bingmaps-control-wp7-mvvm/) may also help you get started.